# Typing Axios interceptor (axios.create) response typescript definitions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, typescript, axios

I am currently working on a react typescript app and I'm trying to properly type my axios interceptor. I can't seem to figure out exactly how to crack the types.

**TL;DR The Problem: TS not recognizing my axios interceptor response configuration types properly.**

**My Code**
--Interceptor creation

```js
const client = axios.create({
  baseURL: apiURL
});

export const api = < T,
  D > ({ ...options
  }: AxiosRequestConfig < D > ) => {
    const token = getToken();

    client.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
    const onSuccess = (response: AxiosResponse < T > ) => response;
    const onError = (error: Error | AxiosError) => {
      if (axios.isAxiosError(error)) {
        if (error.response ? .status === 401) {
          logout();
          window.location.assign(window.location.href);
          return Promise.reject({
            message: 'Please re-authenticate.'
          });
        } else {
          return error;
        }
      }
      return error;
    };

    return client(options).then(onSuccess).catch(onError);
  };

export default api;
```

**Using the Axios Instance**

```js
// I created a generic shown in the previous code used to define the response type
api < USER > ({
    url: 'auth/me'
  })
  .then((response) => { // Error | AxiosResponse<User>
    // have to add typeguards for TS not to complain that it COULD be type ERROR
    if (!(response instanceof Error)) {
      setUser(response.data);
      setStatus('success');
    }
  })
  // here, TS doesn't know what this is at all ? err: any 
  .catch((err) => { //err: any
    setError(err);
    setStatus('rejected');
  });
```

**The Problem**

As you can see from my code comments, TS FORCES me to type guard a type the "success" scenario (meaning the request didn't fail), to make sure it's not an error, which is annoying since I already defined what the types should be `onSuccess`. Additionally, I'm not getting any Type definitions in my `.catch` method.

I know that promises can return errors in both the `.then` and the `.catch`, but why can't I get TS to figure out that I will be using `.catch` for errors when I have clearly passed it the proper typings?

Thanks for all your help! I'm **really** struggling here. There has been a good bit of discussion on Axios TS, but I can't seem to find this.

Helpful discussions: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/4176

Comment: I'm not using TS but I found a possible solution her : https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1510#issuecomment-396894600

Comment: Thank you for this @ag-dev, it was helpful, just not exactly it! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be returning the error `return error;` in the API function which is why TypeScript is forcing you to check the type in the `then` clause because it is expecting an error as a possible return type. Catch clause is only run when an error is thrown `throw error` or when a promise is rejected `Promise.reject`.

Comment: this is incredible! You're absolutely right! Oddly enough though, even though I no longer have to typeguard my `.then` responses, I still don't get any type safety in my `.catch` statements, it defaults to `err: any`. And, oddly enough it's not even making me typeguard the errors either. 

Any thoughts as to why this is? Thanks a million times over man!

Comment: Catch clause errors are always defaulted to `any` unless configured to default to `unknown` (https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#useUnknownInCatchVariables). You can also just explicitly type the variable as unknown `catch(err: unknown) {`. I do not understand what you mean that it is not allowing you to typeguard the errors in catch clause.

Comment: You might find this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69021040/why-catch-clause-variable-type-annotation-must-be-any

Comment: Thank you for explaining that @Michael Boñon!