# Can I use satisfies to check if an any has a property?

Tags: typescript

```
  } catch (error: any) {
    let msg = 'failed to parse polygon geometry';
    if (error satisfies { hint: string }) msg += ` ${error.hint}`;
    logger.error(msg, { error });
```

I have a library that has [very minimal Typescript descriptions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/terraformer__wkt). It throws errors that have a `hint` property but it doesn't export that type. Can I use `satisfies` + `any` + an inline type to stand in for "does this error have the `hint` property?"

If I leave off the `:any` the type is `unknown` and  I get a TS error: "error is of type unknown". But if it's `unknown` I can't check for the existence of the property (or don't know how to).

I've seen other answers to this but none of the really apply to an object that is of an inaccessible type.

Comment: This is not a use case of the satisfies. It doesn't act like a type guard. Instead you should do something like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4JwngBA3gUAvhAxgQ2IgFhAFAUxCAexAC4IBXAOwGsKCB3CgSmhgjYgBsdgIBbAZwDmEALwQA5ADNkASy4ATCMAIQADshD8caghzCCCFCIJwFe3cOIDcrdjMnZb7dnkIgIAMg9PnSsKtMHVyJRETFxAgAjACscRGBxT29fdnF0GQoEiAyIYPcvH2dgf0Dc-CIAOnTM0PD+UAzBcR9GQvYBYQBqMQADCAASKDyqjOA4Hps4GCA). Of course this approach can be improved to become a concise and readable if you would like to proceed

Comment: it's insane to me that I have to add 5 lines of code just to see if an object has a property

Comment: as I said, this can be improved, by extracting the logic into a separate type guard like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlhA8gIwFYFNiwLwwDwAqM6AHlOmACYQwhqZQB8AFAFAwwCGATgOYBcMAK5gA1mBAB3MABpWASkE9e8GgG92MANoBpeGBij0ATxAAzGAQC6gkeKlgA3KwC+MbIxhRjAB3TmuPndsXAByOgwsUJgAMhjAlQBCEJgwIQAbdNj4xIBBbm5OYwA6BHzC42ZleWdWKG5jGA03YE4oYAALGGZ0ApBuWzEJaXkmzXT0WABbCBUws044CcovEBgfHgh0dZB0415wGF5-KcmG0OcOOAtmBBRIqDw1GA64MChBaG43lRcWXu4-VGcS8vn8FgB-WKr3ewTCXx+oXkmg4MxUAGpcAADGAAEjUkO40LeUBcWOcLlYQA). Would this work?

Comment: As I understand you don't want to proceed with this method, right?

Comment: @jcollum _"it's insane to me that I have to add 5 lines of code just to see if an object has a property"_ As to wonderflame's example, that is how it is done in JS. TS is simply alerting you to the fact that anything simpler is actually unsafe. How would _you_ do it in plain JS?

Comment: In JS you'd just treat `error.hint` as a boolean/truthy: `if (error.hint) msg += ....`

Comment: Works for me: https://tsplay.dev/NaR7Bm

Comment: @DarrylNoakes the point is to do it without `any`

Comment: As I said, "anything simpler is actually unsafe". To clarify: that code I linked to _works_, but has issues. For example, it would fail if `undefined` or `null` were thrown for some reason. Which is the minimum safe code is to at least check the truthiness of the root value first.

Comment: I agree and also changing the type of the error to something else is not a good approach, which also raises an error by some eslint rule

Comment: An explanation, for anyone who wants it. The crux is that TS doesn't like accessing properties that aren't specified to be on an object, so you either need to use a type intersection (specifying the property of interest as optional) or the `in` operator. Plain `error.hint` fails if the value is `undefined` or `null`, so truthiness must be checked in some way. The `in` operator requires that the target is an object, so the same applies.

Comment: If you don't want a type intersection, you will have to use `in`; this requires the target to be an object. This can be checked using `error instanceof Object`, as shown by _hackape_; this checks truthiness at the same time. Using `typeof` is awkward, because `typeof null === 'object'`, so we have to check both truthiness first and the type.

Comment: Then, for semantic safety (can't remember the correct name), you may want to check that the property is also a string. E.g., `&& typeof error.hint === "string"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
} catch (error: Error & { hint?: string }) {
    let msg = 'failed to parse polygon geometry';
    if (typeof error?.hint == 'string') msg += ` ${error.hint}`;
    logger.error(msg, { error });
```

This is the way I’ll go about.

A more generic version:

```
} catch (error) {
    let msg = 'failed to parse polygon geometry';
    if (error instanceof Object && 'hint' in error) msg += ` ${error.hint}`;
    logger.error(msg, { error });
```

Comment: doesn't that remove the `message` property of all errors though? I need to rethrow the error at the end too

Comment: TS does not work at runtime, so it does not "remove" nor "add" anything visible at runtime.

Comment: I just added in `Error &` to make things more obvious for you, does that help?

Comment: yeah that's better, that way the code can still see a real error instead of the subset

Comment: It's obvious that I'm still learning so saying "your understanding of TS is flawed" is very unhelpful and rude. Reconsider how you talk to people. edit: mods took it out, cool

Answer (score 0):

The [`satisfies`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) keyword is not a javascript operator, so you cannot use it in an `if` statement.

it might be easier to use the [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator for this validation.

```js
} catch (error: any) {
    let msg = 'failed to parse polygon geometry';

    if ('hint' in error) msg += ` ${error.hint}`;

    logger.error(msg, { error });
}
```

The `in`operator returns `true` when the property exists in the object.

**EDIT** Turns out [Typescript errors HAS to have the type "unknown" or "any"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69021180/5784924). Becuse of that, might have to create a new type for the error, and use the `as` keyword.

```js
type HintableError = Error & { hint: string }

try {

} catch (error: unknown) {
    let msg = 'failed to parse polygon geometry';

    if ('hint' in (error as HintableError)) msg += ` ${(error as HintableError).hint}`;

    console.error(msg, { error });
}
```

It's not pretty, so a better way to do it would be to create a function that handle the logging, so you could use a parameter, and only "cast" the `error` variable one time.

[here is a workable playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/C4TwDgpgBAEglgO2AQwEYBsIFEBOOD2OUAvFLgUQGRQDeUAFosAFxQDOwOiA5lAL4AoAZxC0hfKAGNkwSfSgAKCHkKsArggDWCfAHcEASjFQTUTMCgBbNr1IByAGbI4mACZRg+KGGQ420MHx0EG58BChuCHxLCBE7AG4hUyg4B0U7RiQ7FPClFSJkNlgmNExyQgMja14AalIAAygAEho8iihC4qRS7HyDADpM4D56xIFkyTC2IIh+5QoFaoAaWih5wn4DRL4gA)

P.S. Thanks to [hackape's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76758378/5784924) for the `Error &`, I did not think of that.

Comment: it will work if the `error` is any  though

Comment: this triggers `@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any` which I'm trying to avoid -- TS is now making the error object an `unknown` type

Comment: also, `satisfies` is an operator. Docs: `The satisfies Operator`

Comment: >The new satisfies operator lets us validate that the type of an expression matches some type, without changing the resulting type of that expression. As an example, we could use satisfies to validate that all the properties of palette are compatible with string | number[]:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9-beta/#the-satisfies-operator

Comment: the problem is that `satisfies` isn't a runtime operator. So there is no way for the compiler to use it as a type-guard

Comment: @jcollum I meant it's not an operator in Javascript, it's used by Typescript to catch error _before_ it's compile to JS. When compiled, it does not means anythings, this is why you cannot use it to validate a condition in an if, like you could for `===`.

Comment: @jcollum _"lets us validate that the type of an expression matches some type"_ As stated, it operates on the _type_ of the expression, not its value.